# Update Multiple Firebase nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update few nodes in firebase data which is posted from the **server end**.Need to update the node "is_done" to 0/1 from the device end.I have tried with different solutions but all became futile i.e it is adding a different node outside the "schedule" node.

**Code snippet I have tried**

```
private void updatemultiplefirebasedata() {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        Query query = reference.child("schedule").child("22-12-2017").child("route").child("1").child("kid").child("21");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d("Keys",String.valueOf(d.getKey())); //returning all the keys
                        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                        result.put("is_done", "0");
                    reference.child(String.valueOf(d.getKey())).updateChildren(result);  //update according to keys
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

[image: This is the firebase data structure]

Comment: All the keys are coming properly in log ?

Comment: Yes, it is returning 1,2

Comment: Check my answer @avik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your database reference still points to the root of your tree. You should assign the desired path to that `reference`.

Also: You don't need Queries in order to access data directly. You can simply attach a listener to the Database Reference.

```
private void updatemultiplefirebasedata() {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference reference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("schedule").child("22-12-2017").child("route").child("1").child("kid").child("21");
        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.d("Keys",String.valueOf(d.getKey())); //returning all the keys
                        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
                        result.put("is_done", "0");
                    reference.child(String.valueOf(d.getKey())).updateChildren(result);  //update according to keys
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: If the update is done inside for loop then it can also be directly updated using `set` since its always setting the value to 0.

Comment: Otherwise hashmap should be populated in for loop and update should be called outside loop appropriately to update all the values in single call.

Comment: @UmarHussain Good point. Feel free to hit that edit button and update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
reference.child(d.getKey()).updateChildren(result);
```

remove String.valueOf from child because your key is integer and you are passing it as string so instead of pointing it to same `child` it will create new key with `String "1"`